# How Can I get item id

Tags: java, android

I have recyclerview on my project . I want get item id . How Can I get item id ? . I used Item touchhelper and I need particular item id . How can I get particular item id .

**Activty.java**

```
public class todoactivity extends AppCompatActivity    {
    TextView title;
    Button back;
    ImageButton gorevo;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<String>Listsx = new ArrayList<>();
    TodoActivityAdpter adapterx;
    DatabaseHelper4 myDBxxx;
    TextView textView;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    long id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_todoactivity);
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewxx);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        adapterx=new TodoActivityAdpter(Listsx);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterx);
        title=findViewById(R.id.titlex);
        textView=findViewById(R.id.text_viewx);
        gorevo = findViewById(R.id.gorevo);

        myDBxxx = new DatabaseHelper4(this);

        Cursor datax = myDBxxx.getListContents();
        if(datax.getCount() == 0){

        }else{
            while(datax.moveToNext()){
                Listsx.add(datax.getString(1));

                ListAdapter listAdapterx = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.todoactivity_item,R.id.textitem,Listsx);
                adapterx.notifyItemInserted(Listsx.size()-1);
            }
        }


        gorevo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(todoactivity.this);
                bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.bottomsheetlayout3);
                bottomSheetDialog.show();
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
                EditText editText = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.editx);
                Button ekle = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.ekle);
                ekle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        String text = editText.getText().toString();
                        Listsx.add(text);
                        AddDataxxx(text);
                        adapterx.notifyItemInserted(Listsx.size()-1);
                        bottomSheetDialog.hide();
                        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        back=findViewById(R.id.back);
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(todoactivity.this, pomodoroscreen.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(0,0);
            }
        });



        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

                int positionx = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                Listsx.remove(positionx);
                adapterx.notifyItemRemoved(positionx);
                myDBxxx.deleteItem(// I want get id in there);
                

}
};
       
        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
     
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        
    }

    public void AddDataxxx(String newEntry) {

        boolean insertDatax = myDBxxx.addDataxxx(newEntry);
    }


}
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class TodoActivityAdpter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoActivityAdpter.Holder> {



    List<String>Listsx;
    public TodoActivityAdpter(List<String>itemxxx){
        this.Listsx = itemxxx;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TodoActivityAdpter.Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.todoactivity_item,parent,false);
        Holder holder = new Holder(view);
        return holder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TodoActivityAdpter.Holder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(Listsx.get(position));


        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (holder.checkBox.isChecked()) {


                    holder.textView.setTextColor(view.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
                } else {
                    holder.textView.setTextColor(view.getResources().getColor(R.color.Color_black));
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Listsx.size();
    }

    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CheckBox checkBox;
        TextView textView;

        List<String>Listsx;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        Context mContext;
        public Holder(View view) {
            super(view);

            textView=view.findViewById(R.id.text_viewx);
            checkBox=view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewxx);



        }
    }
   
}
```

I want get item id in Activty . How Can I get item id  . Can you be fast . My actvity is **activity.java** . My adapter is **MyAdapter.java**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get ID of the items in recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41919116/how-to-get-id-of-the-items-in-recyclerview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int positionx = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
int id = recyclerView.getChildAt(position).getId();
Listsx.remove(positionx);
adapterx.notifyItemRemoved(positionx);
myDBxxx.deleteItem(id);
```

maybe

Comment: Its always good to add some explanation to your answers :)

Comment: It cant work for me